# How to capture window focus events in autoit v3

Tags: autoit

Let's say i have some Windows open, Then i start my **AutoIt** script.

Now whenever user clicks on a window it gets focused (activated), Here i want to execute some code.

So basically i want to capture some kind of **windowFocused** or **windowActivated** event.

- One way to do it would be to get list of all windows using **WinList()**, loop through them, check which one is active using **WinActive()** but it'll be too inefficient since this checking will have to be performed in an infinite loop.

I want some better solution than a infinite-loop.

Answer (score 0):

This is still using an infinite-loop, which I'm not sure how you can get away from if you are always looking for Windows. But you don't have to use WinList(). Just a simple while loop:

```
While 1
  If WinActive("Notepad") Then
      ; do something    
  ElseIf WinActive("Wordpad") Then
      ; do something else
  EndIf
WEnd
```

Comment: WinList() is necessary because script will not know anything about 'currently' open windows not even their titles etc.

Comment: @JonBecher: Your edit is appreciated, but you don't need to use `<br>` tags and surround the text with \`\`. You can either indent everything with four spaces, or select the text and use the code formatting (CTRL+K) button.